# Disable javascript analysis in resharper?

Tags: javascript, resharper

When I use extjs javascript library in VS2012 project, resharper appears a stopper for the development - slow VS response, big memory usage, Ctrl+N, Ctrl+F12 give me tons of useless options. 
I like resharper for c# development, but don't like for js.

How can I disable javascript analysis and leave for c#?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can only turn off intellisense for JavaScript now. But we plan to make more options for turning off JavaScript support in the next ReSharper versions.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry, looking forward for updates of your great product

Answer (score 25):

We are constantly optimizing the performance, and I hope that in 9.0 it would be much better, but currently in 8.1 you have an option to completely disable JavaScript support in ReSharper by turning off options "JavaScript" and "TypeScript" in ReSharper | Options -> Environment | Languages.

Comment: In VS2013 with ReSharper9.1 the option can be found at 

ReSharper | Options -> Environment -> Products & Features

Comment: When working with typescript, it should be possible to disable *.js without at the same time disabling *.ts, because I am not interested in having resharper validate the .js output of compiled typescript.

Comment: Why is Javascript and Typescript grouped together? ReSharper is doing a good job with Javascript, but is failing to work with Typescript properly, so I only want to disable Typescript!

Answer (score 10):

[TypeScript 1.8 was the last supported release for VS 2013](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11214#issuecomment-250311555)

[Download latest version of TypeScript for Visual Studio 2013 is 1.8.5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48739)

If you are using Resharper to get the proper syntax highlighting you will need to disable it's support for TypeScript so that the VS 2013 TypeScript is used instead.

In Resharper 8.2 go navigate to ReSharper | <kbd>Options - Environment - Languages</kbd>

[image]

In Resharper 9.2 navigate to ReSharper | <kbd>Options - Environment - Products & Features</kbd>

[image]

This is needed as ReSharper only recognizes syntax up to TypeScript 1.6 version.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with Typescript. You can keep you ReSharper but remove the file types that you don't like it to process by adding it as third party code like I did for typescript in the screenshot.

[image]